# The answer listed is months = 142, where as when I input the same variables I get months = 128.? is the problem with my loop variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

This code is intented to find the amount of months it takes pay off the downpayment value (.25) of a house.

```
annual_salary = float(input('Enter your annual salary:')) #120000

portion_saved = float(input('Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:')) #.05

total_cost = float(input('Enter the cost of your dream home:')) #500000

semi_annual_raise = float(input('Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal: ')) #.03

portion_down_payment = .25 * total_cost
current_savings = 0
annual_return_rate = .04

portion_saved_monthly = annual_salary / 12 * portion_saved

current_savings = current_savings + portion_saved_monthly

month = 1
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += (current_savings * annual_return_rate / 12) + portion_saved_monthly
    month += 1
    if month % 6 == 0:
        annual_salary += annual_salary * semi_annual_raise
        portion_saved_monthly = annual_salary / 12 * portion_saved
        current_savings += (current_savings * annual_return_rate / 12) + portion_saved_monthly

print('Number of months: ', month)
```

Comment: oh i see, its probably not an ideal format, but i have added **current_savings -= (current_savings * annual_return_rate / 12) + portion_saved_monthly**to start the if statement. Seems to Work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increase the savings rate every 6 months when they get a raise, you make two deposits into savings. You do the normal add to savings before the `if`, and then again at the new rate inside the `if`.

Removing that line from the `if` block produces the expected result.

```
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += (current_savings * annual_return_rate / 12) + portion_saved_monthly
    month += 1
    if month % 6 == 0:
        annual_salary += annual_salary * semi_annual_raise
        portion_saved_monthly = annual_salary / 12 * portion_saved
```

Comment: Thank You! I was over thinking this and added **current_savings -= (current_savings * annual_return_rate / 12) + portion_saved_monthly** to start the if statement instead. Your way seems much better!